# Zoom Conference broke with latest 18.04 update

Tags: 18.04, screen

After updating system dependencies recently for 18.04, switching my workspace causes the screen to freeze (mouse still moves) for 30+ seconds. Wondering if anyone else has seen this behavior.

Comment: Upgrade to the latest version, available on Zoom website.